# JDBC setting for special character in mysql database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have jdbc driver like this

```
jdbc:mysql://www.site.com:3306/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

and datamodel in database

```
utf8_unicode_ci
```

Why when I send something like "ą", "ł" i always gets

```
 Got an exception!
  Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x85\xC4\x85\xC4\x85' for column 'name'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the charset of the column in question to UTF-8 as well. DB collation sometime may not affect the table or column charset. it's possible for database columns to have a different character set in MySQL.